# Wordpress ajax - get_attached_media return empty array

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I tried to create wordpress ajax call that should return images attached to a post but get_attached_media function returns an empty array. I can get any post data but not attached images. Here is what I have done:

in functions.php:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_getGallery', 'getGallery');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_getGallery', 'getGallery');

function getGallery() {
    $pid = $_REQUEST["post_id"];
    $n = 1;       
    $gallery = get_attached_media('image', $pid);// this $gallery returns an empty array
    foreach($gallery as $item) {
            if ($n > 5) {
                    $img_object = wp_get_attachment_image_src($item->ID,'gallerythumb');
                    $img = $img_object[0];
                    $str .= '<div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-4"><div class="img-holder"><img class="img-responsive" src="' . $img . '" /></div></div>';
                    $n++;
            }
    }
    echo $str;

    die();
}
```

and in .js:

```
$(".post-link").click(function(){

    var post_id = $(this).attr("rel");
    $("#post-container").html("content loading");
    $.ajax({
        url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            action: 'getGallery',
            post_id: post_id
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            $("#post-container").html(data);
        },
        fail: {
        }
    });
    return false;    
});
```

Does anyone knows why I can't get images here? All code seams fine to me. 
Thnx.

Comment: try 'image/jpeg', image/png', ...

Comment: tried with 'image/jpeg' still empty.

Comment: Sorry.. my mistake. I passed wrong ID :(
Thanx for help anyway.